# Firefox 3.5 warns that page contains unauthenticated content

Tags: css, https

We are receiving the warning in FF 3.5 that warns of unencrypted content (partially encrypted page). We never received any such warning in FF 3.0. The page we are loading does a single get request for an HTML page using https, no other requests are made for things like CSS, JS, Images, etc.

Has anyone else experienced this problem with FF 3.5?
Any troubleshooting techniques to identify the content that is being flagged as unencrypted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was actually due to lightbox. The following is defined in the lightbox CSS file:

```
background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,AAAA); /*Trick IE into showing hover*/
```

It uses an image encoded inline (base64). It is known as [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

We are lucky in that we do not have to support IE 6 or 7 so we have simply removed the background image and this solved the problem and lightbox still functions fine in Firefox. I have not tested in IE 8, but since it is "more" standards compliant I am hoping the hack won't be needed.

By the way, identifying the content that was causing the problem was actually very simple. The media tab in page info displays everything the page downloaded. I was relying on Firebug to tell me everything but it didn't. The media section clearly defined what content was received via HTTPS and what content was not.

Comment: WTF ... data URI should not be considered unsafe content, that's a fairly screwed up behavior !

Comment: The media tab is not a complete list of loaded URLs. I get this error, but the media tab only shows https URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reproduce the behavior with a "know" good page, i.e.:

```
<html>
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <body>
    <p>This should pass</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If a page such as the one in my example exhibits the behavior it would point to a bug in FF 3.5 but you need to verify it before submitting a bug report to Mozilla.

I would also make sure your HTTPS certificate validates properly! And that your web server is configured properly!! (by the way - what server are you using??)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is what I suggest:

Try calling the page with HTTP FOX and see if mod rewrite is changing the images from https:... to http:... In other words look for any content that is coming over http:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/

If you see any resources coming over http://, that is the problem.

Adding **this rule** to .htaccess (or mod_ssl.conf) solved the problem for me:

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(checkout|process|thanks|terms).php$
**RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(png|gif|jpg|css|js|swf)$**
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]